# Jetpack Compose not recomposing composable on setValue

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to do a quick pagination example with `Jetpack` compose in where I load the first 6 items of the list, then I load another 6 and so on until the end of the list.

I'm aware of the error in the for loop that will cause an `IndexOutOfBounds` since is not well designed to iterate until the last element of the array

My problem is two, first the for loop one, I don't know how to take from `0 - 6 , 6 - 12 - 12 - list.size`

Then my other problem is that every time I use setList it should recompose the `LazyColumnForIndex` and its not, causing only to render the first 6 items

What I'm doing wrong here ?

```
val longList = mutableListOf("Phone","Computer","TV","Glasses","Cup",
        "Stereo","Music","Furniture","Air","Red","Blue","Yellow",
        "White","Black","Pink","Games","Car","Motorbike")

@Composable
fun PaginationDemo() {
    val maxItemsPerPage = 6
    val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    var (page,setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val (paginatedList,setList) = remember { mutableStateOf(getPaginatedList(page,maxItemsPerPage, list)) }
    LazyColumnForIndexed(items = paginatedList ) { index, item ->

        Text(text = item,style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))

        if(paginatedList.lastIndex == index){
            onActive(callback = {
                setValue(page++)
                setList(getPaginatedList(page,maxItemsPerPage,list))
            })
        }
    }
}

private fun getPaginatedList(page:Int,maxItemsPerPage:Int,list:MutableList<String>): MutableList<String> {
    val startIndex = maxItemsPerPage * page
    for(item in 0 until startIndex){
        list.add(longList[item])
    }
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
@Composable
fun PaginationDemo() {
    val maxItemsPerPage = 6
    val list = mutableStateListOf<String>()
    var (page,setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val (paginatedList,setList) = remember { mutableStateOf(getPaginatedList(page,maxItemsPerPage, list)) }
    LazyColumnForIndexed(
        items = paginatedList
    ) { index, item ->
        Text(
            text = item,
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillParentMaxWidth()
                .height((ConfigurationAmbient.current.screenHeightDp / 3).dp)
                .background(color = Color.Blue)
        )
        Divider(thickness = 2.dp)

        Log.d("MainActivity", "lastIndex = ${paginatedList.lastIndex} vs index = $index")
        if(paginatedList.lastIndex == index){
            onActive(callback = {
                setValue(++page)
                setList(getPaginatedList(page,maxItemsPerPage,list))
            })
        }
    }
}

private fun getPaginatedList(page:Int,maxItemsPerPage:Int,list:MutableList<String>): MutableList<String> {
    val maxSize = longList.size
    val startIndex = if (maxItemsPerPage * page >= maxSize) maxSize else maxItemsPerPage * page
    list.clear()
    for(item in 0 until startIndex){
        list.add(longList[item])
    }

    return list
}
```

Comment: what I see is that the for loop always starts at 0 , hmm , I think we need something like 0 - 6 , 6 - 12 , -6 - 18, but this for loop goes 0 - 6 , 0 - 12 , 0 - 18, thanks for your contribution !

Comment: In my opinion, 0 - 6, 0 - 12, 0 - 18, it is like the endless scroll.  for 0 - 6, 6 - 12, 12 - 18, you might consider using pager instead.